# CTE is behaving unexpectedly when an aggregate function is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

When I'm using an aggregate function inside CTE, I'm getting an error message. Below is the query and the error message associated with it. It is working fine when I remove the aggregate function. Somewhere I'm missing the trick.

**Code:**

```
;
With CTE as (
    Select
        sn,
        ed,
        sum(c) c,
        row_number() over (partition by sn, ed order by sn, sum(c) desc, ed) rn
    from TD
    where ed >= '11/15/2018'
)
select * from CTE
```

**Error message:**

> Column `TD.sn` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.

Comment: That `sum(c)` you've got there means you need a `group by sn, ed` to make the rest of the columns actually group, otherwise it's not clear what you're going for. Maybe you wanted to window the `sum` as well: `sum(c) over (...)`. Or else you need another subquery.

Comment: Yeah! I want to window the sum as well. If I use group by sn, ed then I'm not getting expected results. Row_number won't work in that case.

Comment: can you explain what results do you expect from this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used aggregate function but not used group by in your query

```
With CTE as (
    Select
        sn,
        ed,
        sum(c) c,
        row_number() over (partition by sn order by  sum(c) desc) rn
    from TD
    where ed >= '11/15/2018'
   group by sn,
        ed
)
select * from CTE where rn<=3
```

Comment: If I use below query, row_number stays at 1 for each row. I want the top three c for each sn for a particular ed. Example: for sn 'a', there are two ed 1 and 2. So there are two rows with different c. I want the rownumber to display 1 and 2 based on the maximum value of c

Comment: @Madhukar i have not seen your sample data and output so i just correct your your code and i think you have to change partition by and order by column and i edite query you may check now